# How to combine objects with objects.assign?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

My simple code

```
const ob1 = {
  a: 'pokushevski',
  b: '2001',
};

const obj2 = {
  obj1: {},
  c: '1999',
};

const result = Object.assign(ob1, obj2);
console.log(result);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(result));
```

Output

```
{ a: 'pokushevski', b: '2001', obj1: {}, c: '1999' }
[ 'a', 'b', 'obj1', 'c' ]
```

It seems that `obj1` in result appears just as any other attribute,without having any reference to `const obj1`.
Why?

Comment: `Object.assign()` mutates the object of the first parameter, you should use object destruction/spread: `const result = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };`

Comment: Could you show us what your expected output is?

Comment: @HaoWu This won;t work,try it yourself.

Comment: `const result = { ...obj2, ...{ obj1 } };` Maybe this is what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing right now is basically merging `ob1` (without 'j') with `obj2` (with 'j'), and since `obj1` (with 'j') is an empty object inside of `obj2`, it gets added as a property on the resulting merged object.

What else did you expect, and can we help in getting you there?

Maybe you actually made a typo and wanted the first object `ob1` to be named `obj1` instead, then to be used as a property within `obj2` and finally merge the two objects?

If so you co do:

```js
const obj1 = {
  a: 'pokushevski',
  b: '2001',
};

const obj2 = {
  obj1, // shorthand syntax, property will be named the same as the const
  c: '1999',
};

// avoid mutation by using a new object as the target
const result = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);

// Display result and property names
console.log(result);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(result));
```

If you only wanted to add `obj1` within `obj2` you don't need `Object.assign`

#### Watch out for what's mutable

With the code above, the original `obj1` gets modified whenever you update `result.obj1` properties. Try to update `result.obj1.a` and then `console.log(obj1)`

If you want to prevent this, you can use destructuring like so:

```js
const obj1 = {
  a: 'pokushevski',
  b: '2001',
};

// Create a shallow copy of `obj1` to prevent mutating the original
// object by updating `obj2.obj1` properties
const obj2 = {
  obj1: {...obj1},
  c: '1999',
};

// Avoid mutating the original `obj1` by using a new object as the target
const result = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);

// Display result and property names
console.log(result);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(result))
```

If you really want to keep using `Object.assign` instead of destructuring you can replace `obj1: {...obj1}` by `obj1: Object.assign({}, obj1)`

Comment: How to insert obj into obj2?

Comment: Updated answer based on my understanding

Comment: Yeah,it was typo.

Comment: May I ask you something? Why not `const result = Object.assign({obj1}, obj2);`? I don't mean to offend you but just out of curiosity. I'm kinda new to JS, so I'm wondering if there is a technical reason.

Comment: It really depends on how you want to structure the resulting object and what you want to be mutable or not. But with what you suggest, we would overwrite the `{obj1}` by merging `obj2` which already contains an `obj1`, and then the top level properties `a` and `b` would not be merged as the OP intents seems to be

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply :) Sorry to ask again. `const result = Object.assign({obj1}, obj2);` seems to have a right structure. I'm not good at seeing console, so I'm sorry if I'm wrong. https://ibb.co/f9SXT4f

Comment: I am so sorry to post many times. The sugar syntax way and `Object.assign()` seem to output different results. That is why I'm confused. I think the sugar syntax's result is what the OP intents?

Comment: From what the OP seemed to ask, he's expecting the following structure for `result`: `{ a: 'pokushevski', b: '2001', obj1: {a: 'pokushevski', b: '2001'}, c: '1999' }`

Comment: Let's say `obj1 = {a: '...', b: '...'}` and `obj2 = {c: '...'}` (without obj1 property) then what you could do would be: `result = Object.assign({}, obj1, {obj1}, obj2)` but then again, the original `obj1` would be mutable by updating `result.obj1` props so if you need to prevent that you should do `result = Object.assign({}, obj1, {obj1: Object.assign({}, obj1)}, obj2)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply and patience. `Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2)` doesn't seem to output `{ a: 'pokushevski', b: '2001', obj1: {a: 'pokushevski', b: '2001'}, c: '1999' }`. It outputs this: `{a: "pokushevski", b: "2001", c: "1999"}`.

Comment: Ah! I got it. Do I have to use the `Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2)` with the sugar syntax together?

Comment: I don't know what part you're calling "syntactic sugar" but if you copy paste my code in the console it will output the expected result :)

Comment: I'm sorry for causing you trouble. I think I got it. Thank you so much your kind explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you want ob1 to be obj1 inside obj2

Then this is a way to do it:

```js
const ob1 = {
  a: 'pokushevski',
  b: '2001',
};

const obj2 = {
  obj1: {},
  c: '1999',
};

const result = Object.assign({}, obj2);
Object.assign(result.obj1, ob1);
console.log(result);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(result));
```

Comment: That's a very weird way to do it! Why assign?

Comment: because the question is titled "How to combine objects with objects.assign?"

Comment: I guess it all comes down to how mutable OP wants his original `ob1` (or `obj1`) to be :)